# Get selected Text from WPF Tree View

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview

I am displaying a tree view in WPF as follows.

```
<TreeView Height="332" Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="White" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,46,0,0" Name="treeView1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="182" MouseDoubleClick="treeView1_MouseDoubleClick" SelectedItemChanged="treeView1_SelectedItemChanged">

        <TreeViewItem >
            <TreeViewItem.Header>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Image Source="../Images/Logos/Gway.png" Height="24" Width="24"></Image>
                    <Label Content="Gway"></Label>
                </StackPanel>
            </TreeViewItem.Header>

            <!-- Child Item -->

            <TreeViewItem>
                <TreeViewItem.Header>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Image Source="../Images/Logos/Scan.png"  Height="24" Width="24"></Image>
                        <Label Content="Scan"></Label>                           
                    </StackPanel>                       
                </TreeViewItem.Header>
            </TreeViewItem>

            <TreeViewItem>
                <TreeViewItem.Header>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Image Source="../Images/Logos/Configuration.png"  Height="24" Width="24"></Image>
                        <Label Content="Config"></Label>
                    </StackPanel>
                </TreeViewItem.Header>
            </TreeViewItem>

        </TreeViewItem>


        <TreeViewItem >
            <TreeViewItem.Header>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Image Source="../Images/Logos/Fiware_1.png" Height="24" Width="24"></Image>
                    <Label Content="Fi ware"></Label>
                </StackPanel>
            </TreeViewItem.Header>              

        </TreeViewItem>

        <TreeViewItem >
            <TreeViewItem.Header>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Image Source="../Images/Logos/data.png" Height="24" Width="24"></Image>
                    <Label Content="Request"></Label>
                </StackPanel>
            </TreeViewItem.Header>

            <!-- Child Item -->

            <TreeViewItem>
                <TreeViewItem.Header>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Image Source="../Images/Logos/assign.png"  Height="24" Width="24"></Image>
                        <Label Content="Assign"></Label>
                    </StackPanel>
                </TreeViewItem.Header>
            </TreeViewItem>

            <TreeViewItem>
                <TreeViewItem.Header>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Image Source="../Images/Logos/update.png"  Height="24" Width="24"></Image>
                        <Label Content="Update"></Label>
                    </StackPanel>
                </TreeViewItem.Header>
            </TreeViewItem>

            <TreeViewItem>
                <TreeViewItem.Header>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Image Source="../Images/Logos/UnAssign.png"  Height="24" Width="24"></Image>
                        <Label Content="Unassign"></Label>
                    </StackPanel>
                </TreeViewItem.Header>
            </TreeViewItem>

            <TreeViewItem>
                <TreeViewItem.Header>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Image Source="../Images/Logos/Delete.png"  Height="24" Width="24"></Image>
                        <Label Content="Delete"></Label>
                    </StackPanel>
                </TreeViewItem.Header>
            </TreeViewItem>

        </TreeViewItem>

    </TreeView>
```

And trying to handle the double click event on a node. But not able to get the selected text/value(Here it is Gway,Scan etc..) from the event arguments/sender. The following is the event handler code.

```
private void treeView1_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        object s = e.Source;

        TreeView obj = (TreeView) s;

        TreeViewItem item2 =(TreeViewItem)obj.SelectedItem;// item2 doesnt have any selctedText/ value property


    }
```

please help me out.

Comment: You want to get the label and image values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it is the tree view item it has a tree beneath so it is not just a simple text, so in order to get what is there you can refer to the following and use any approach which suits your need

- Header property of TreeViewItem for the caption displayed there (only if set)
- ItemsSource property for retrieving the collection bound below
- DataContext for retrieving the data bound to it (cast it to appropriate type) and retrieve your desired value.